# Mysql select on condition that date is in set of dates

Tags: mysql

My select command:

```
select * from wp_ved_currencies where date in (select DISTINCT date from wp_ved_currencies order by date desc limit 2);
```

Error message:

```
Error
SQL query:Documentation


select * from wp_ved_currencies where date in (select distinct date from wp_ved_currencies order by date desc limit 2) LIMIT 0, 50
MySQL said:Documentation

#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Could you help me here?

Comment: Is this related to your other question where you needed to find latest rate for one/all currencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to join to a limit subquery here:

```
SELECT w1.*
FROM wp_ved_currencies w1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT date
    FROM wp_ved_currencies
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 2
) w2
    ON w1.date = w2.date;
```